# error: Failed to find newest available Simulator runtime

Tags: xcode, apple-vision, visionos, ios-vision

## Env

- Intel Core i7
- macOS :14.0
- Xcode 15 Beta 8
- simulator:visionOS 1.0 beta 3(21N5233e)
- simulator: ios 17.0.1 ,ios 17.0 beta 8

## Step

when `init` a vision demo can't build

Is Intel not support vision demo? I’m not sure is only apple silicon support vison demo.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewZHr.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqei6.jpg)